# Problem with cakephp validation

Tags: php, regex, validation, cakephp

I have field in my model whose validation rules is shown below.

```
        'message' => array(
                'rule' => '/^[a-z0-9#.,&; ]{2,255}$/i',
        'required' => true,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => '(message field contains only a-z0-9#.,&; and is between 2 to 255 characters.).'
        ),
```

This works fine. When I add **forwardslash(/)** to the rule `'/^[a-z0-9#.,&;/ ]{2,255}$/i'` or `'/^[a-z0-9#.,&;\/ ]{2,255}$/i'`. then it does not work.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Ivanka, it is simply no longer a valid regular expression when you have three slashes in your term. See my answer for clarification, yours

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a backslash, it is a forward slash.
So I don't know which slash you want to use, but one of these should work:

`'/^[a-z0-9#.,&;\\ ]{2,255}$/i'`

or

`'/^[a-z0-9#.,&;\/ ]{2,255}$/i'`

Comment: sorry my bad. you are right. It is forward slash. Updated the same. Still unable to get it to work.

Comment: It appears to be working for me. Could you provide a string that fails but you think should pass?